# Customizing ModelViewSet to point to same URL for Get and Patch

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am having a modelViewSet for users.

Now for `/api/users` I get a list of users which is a basic function for a modelViewSet for **GET**.
And If go with `/api/users/id` it will take me to **UPDATE** or **PARTIAL UPDATE** which is **PUT** or **PATCH** rest call respectively.

What I want to achieve is for same `/api/users` I can do **GET**,**POST** and **PATCH** based on Authentication token passed.

I am new to django. So please correct me if I am missing something. Or is there any better approach.

I am using Default Routers:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', views.UserDetails, base_name='user')
```

Comment: As per the router snippet, it's possible to do as you said. Is there any problem ?

Comment: Did I missed something ? I want to achieve something like for api/user I want patch request to work rather than api/user/id which is default.

Comment: Now I got your point. The possible and elegant solution will be re-write your view [APIview](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) class and handle each HTTP methods seperately and define those endpoint in urls.py

Comment: Else, you could remove the router and do the same with viewset class (not sure about this method)

Comment: If you go with viewset alteration, it may became a headache because you will loose most of the feature of viewset class

Comment: So that would be a best possible option ? Because only patch thing is needed. Else everything has been done.

Comment: If I use APIview rather than ViewSet and routers, It wont come in that api-root list . django default view for routers (Browsable API)

Comment: Update question/problem with your work

Comment: I have done it with custom router action. /api/user/update.